# Java Thread - Is this proper use of synchronized

Tags: java, multithreading, bluetooth

I am using the *Bluetooth* on *Android*; the short of it is that I only want to open a new Thread for receiving if the socket is currently not **connected** - I am testing this using a boolean.

So:

```
class Main {

   protected boolean mConnected;

   public void startClientConnection() {
      ClientRunnable thread = new ClientRunnable() {
         @Override public void manageSocket(BluetoothSocket pSocket) {
            synchronized (this) {
               if (!mConnected) openReadingThread(pSocket);
            } // end synchronized()
         } // end manageSocket()
      }; // end ClientRunnable
   } // end startClientConnection()

} // End CLASS
```

*Edited:*
Essentially, what I need to know is, because the Runnable will be run on a separate Thread, but the **mConnected** variable will only changed in the main Thread, does it need to be synchronized.

Comment: 1. Is it possible for there to be 2 of these threads running at the same times?
  2. Is it important for only 1 thread to be inside of that method at a time?

Comment: @Cruncher Yes, two separate Threads use this method to start a new Thread that opens a Thread for reading input from the Stream. And yes, the Thread to read from the Stream must only be called once. Also, thanks for the switch repoonse.

Answer (score 1):

in this case, each thread you create has its own lock (the object itself)
you should use something static (like a class) for the lock.

Comment: So, use a separate class with static synchronized methods instead?

Answer (score 1):

The simple answer:  mConnected must be accessed only within a synchronized block.  The code you show is good, but the code where you change the value must also be in a synch block.  The reason for this is that otherwize Java is under no obligation to let one thread see changes made by the other.  In this case, you don't *really* need the synch blocks to synchronize anything, just to force each thread to see the other's changes.

Less simple:  This is almost a good case for making mConnected `volatile`.  You could then skip the synchronized block.  But then it would be possible to get two threads in openReadingThread at the same time.

So keep the synch block in your example (which is more for openReadingThread than for mConnected), and either use another when you set mConnected *or* make mConnected volatile.  Volatile fields are expensive, but then so are synch blocks, particularly when you don't need to synchronize but only make a field visible across threads.  I'd say if changes are few and you go through the code above a lot, skip the volatile and use a second synch block.  But if you change the value a lot, go with a volatile mConnected and only one synch block (the one in your example, which is now needed only for the method, not for mConnected).

**Addtional:**  I was about to tell Philipp Sander that he was wrong about the "this" but, on second glance, he's not; it needs fixing.

Comment: Thanks. That tells me everything I need to know! Threading is a complicated issue so I didn't want to get things wrong.